# OpenAI Gym LunarLander execution considerably slowed down for an unknown reason

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, q-learning, dqn

I have been playing around with the OpenAI Gym LunarLander testing a DQN neural network. I had gotten to a point where it was slowly learning. Since I had started with the CartPole problem which was solved in a couple of minutes/episodes, I initially thought that the LunarLander would function at a similar speed but it turns out that I was wrong. After having a decent code that could run correctly and having the neural network learn correctly for about an hour, I thought it's be a good idea to set up a save system for the model after some time of training so I could come back to it later.

I set up all the elements I wanted to have to make sure I could correctly keep track of how the neural network was doing but after getting it all to work, when I launched it with `env.render()` active, the first couple of steps were executing at a decent speed but then, after a specific point, the whole rendering slows right down as if something in the code is taking a long time to process (I haven't managed to pinpoint the exact moment this happens).

Since I've recently started playing around more in depth with keras and Machine Learning in python, I'm still not familiar with how the components behave within a system and which ones take a big hit on computing power.

Here are the two parts of code necessary to run what I have:

`LunarLanderConfig.py`

```
ENVIRONMENT = 'LunarLander-v2'
EPISODES = 10000
POINTS_TO_SOLVE = 200
CONSECUTIVE_EPISODES_TO_SOLVE = 100
MAX_TICKS = 3000

GAMMA = 0.99
ALPHA = 0.001
MEMORY_SIZE = 1000000
EPSILON = 1.0
EPSILON_MIN = 0.01
EPSILON_DECAY = 0.995
BATCH_SIZE = 64
TRAINING_FREQUENCY = 4
```

`LunarLander_AI.py`

```
# IMPORTS
import gym
import random
import sys
import os
from collections import deque

from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.activations import relu, linear
from keras.callbacks import CSVLogger

import numpy as np

from LunarLanderConfig import *

# Save the state of the network to a .h5 file
import h5py
import argparse
import csv


class LunarLanderDQNAgent:
    # Initialise Agent
    def __init__(self):
        # render, test_model = self._args()
        test_model = None
        self.env = gym.make(ENVIRONMENT)
        self.render = True
        self.number_of_actions = self.env.action_space.n
        self.number_of_observations = self.env.observation_space.shape[0]

        self.epsilon = EPSILON # Exploration rate
        self.epsilon_min = EPSILON_MIN
        self.epsilon_decay = EPSILON_DECAY
        self.gamma = GAMMA # Discount factor
        self.alpha = ALPHA # Learning rate
        self.batch_size = BATCH_SIZE
        self.training_frequency = TRAINING_FREQUENCY
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=MEMORY_SIZE)
        self.model = self.build_model()

        self.save_name = ENVIRONMENT+'/'+ENVIRONMENT
        self.history = [('Episode', 'Score', 'Average score', 'Steps', 'Total steps')]
        self.csv_loss_logger = CSVLogger(ENVIRONMENT + '/' + ENVIRONMENT + '_loss.csv', append=True, separator=',')

        if test_model:
            self.load_model(test_model)
            self.test_agent()
        else:
            try:
                os.mkdir(ENVIRONMENT)
            except FileExistsError:
                pass
            self.train_agent()

    # Initialise Neural Network model 
    def build_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=self.number_of_observations, activation=relu))
        model.add(Dense(256, activation=relu))
        model.add(Dense(128, activation=relu))
        model.add(Dense(self.number_of_actions, activation=linear))
        model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=self.alpha), metrics=['accuracy'])
        return model

    # Append the properties of a given state and step in the future
    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    # Choose an action based on the exploration rate and current state of the network
    def choose_action(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return random.randrange(self.number_of_actions)
        q_values = self.model.predict(state)
        return np.argmax(q_values[0])

    def replay(self, total_steps):
        if len(self.memory) < self.batch_size:
            return

        if total_steps % self.training_frequency == 0:
            # Take a random sample of events from memory
            minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, self.batch_size)

            # Calculate Q values for each event and train the model
            for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
                target = reward  

                if not done:
                    # Predict future reward
                    target = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0])

                # Map state to future reward
                target_f = self.model.predict(state)
                target_f[0][action] = target

                # Train model
                self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0, callbacks=[self.csv_loss_logger])

        self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
        self.epsilon = max(self.epsilon_min, self.epsilon)   

    def preprocess_state(self, state):
        return np.reshape(state, (1, self.number_of_observations))

    # Will probably add the train function here
    def train_agent(self):
        try:
            score_history = deque(maxlen=CONSECUTIVE_EPISODES_TO_SOLVE)
            total_steps = 0

            for episode in range(EPISODES):
                # Reset state at the beginning of game
                state = self.preprocess_state(self.env.reset())
                steps = 0
                score = 0

                while True: # Could also iterate to a maximum number of steps/ticks/frames in LunarLanderConfig
                    # Increment step count at each frame
                    steps += 1
                    total_steps += 1

                    # Render or not
                    if self.render:
                        self.env.render()

                    # Choose an action
                    action = self.choose_action(state)

                    # Take action and move to next step
                    next_state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(action)
                    next_state = self.preprocess_state(next_state)

                    # Adjust score
                    score += reward

                    # Add to memory
                    self.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, done)

                    # Train with the experience
                    self.replay(total_steps)

                    if done:
                        score_history.append(score)
                        average_score = np.mean(score_history)

                        text = "[Episode {} of {}] - Score time this episode was {} with epsilon = {}".format(episode, EPISODES, score, self.epsilon)
                        text2 = "- Over last {} episodes: Min = {:.2f}, Mean = {:.2f}, Max = {:.2f}".format(CONSECUTIVE_EPISODES_TO_SOLVE, min(score_history), average_score, max(score_history))
                        text3 = "- Steps this episode: {}, Total steps: {}".format(steps, total_steps)
                        print(text + "\n" + (15 + len(str(episode)) + len(str(EPISODES)))*' '+ text2 + "\n" + (15 + len(str(episode)) + len(str(EPISODES)))*' '+ text3)

                        # Check if the goal has been reached
                        if average_score >= POINTS_TO_SOLVE:
                            print("Lunar Lander solved in {} episodes with an average of {} points".format((episode-CONSECUTIVE_EPISODES_TO_SOLVE), average_score))
                            filename = self.save_name + '_final.h5'
                            print("Saving model to {}".format(filename))
                            self.save_model(filename)
                            sys.exit()
                        break

                    # If not done, advance to the next state for the following iteration
                    state = next_state

                # Save weights every 100 episodes
                if episode % 100 == 0:
                    filename = self.save_name + '_' + str(episode) + '.h5'
                    self.save_model(filename)

            sys.exit()

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # Catch Ctrl+C and end the game correctly
            filename = self.save_name + '_final.h5'
            print("Saving model to {}".format(filename))
            self.save_model(filename)
            self.exit()
        except:
            self.env.close()
            sys.exit()


    def test_agent(self):
        try:
            score_history = deque(maxlen=CONSECUTIVE_EPISODES_TO_SOLVE)
            total_steps = 0

            for episode in range(CONSECUTIVE_EPISODES_TO_SOLVE):
                # Reset state at the beginning of game
                state = self.preprocess_state(self.env.reset())
                steps = 0
                score = 0

                while True: # Could also iterate to a maximum number of steps/ticks/frames in LunarLanderConfig
                    # Increment step count at each frame
                    steps += 1
                    total_steps += 1

                    # Render or not
                    if self.render:
                        self.env.render()

                    # Choose an action
                    action = self.choose_action(state)

                    # Take action and move to next step
                    next_state, reward, done, _ = self.env.step(action)
                    next_state = self.preprocess_state(next_state)

                    # Adjust score
                    score += reward

                    if done:
                        score_history.append(score)
                        average_score = np.mean(score_history)

                        text = "[Episode {} of 99] - Score time this episode was {} with epsilon = {}".format(episode, score, self.epsilon)
                        text2 = "- Over last {} episodes: Min = {:.2f}, Mean = {:.2f}, Max = {:.2f}".format(CONSECUTIVE_EPISODES_TO_SOLVE, min(score_history), average_score, max(score_history))
                        text3 = "- Steps this episode: {}, Total steps: {}".format(steps, total_steps)
                        print(text + "\n" + (17 + len(str(episode)))*' '+ text2 + "\n" + (17 + len(str(episode)))*' '+ text3)
                        break

                    # If not done, advance to the next state for the following iteration
                    state = next_state

            self.env.close()

        except :
            print("Killing game")
            self.env.close()
            sys.exit()

    def exit(self):
        filename = self.save_name + '_history.csv'
        print("Saving training history to {}".format(filename))
        with open(filename, "w") as out:
            csv_out = csv.writer(out)
            for row in self.history:
                csv_out.writerow(row)

        print("Killing game")
        self.env.close()
        sys.exit()

    def save_model(self, filename):
        self.model.save_weights(filename)

    def load_model(self, filename):
        self.model.load_weights(filename)

    # Argument parser for agent options
    def _args(self):
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
        parser.add_argument('-r', '--render', help="Render the game or not", default=True, type=bool)
        parser.add_argument('-tm', '--test_model', help="Filename of model of weights to test the performance of", default=None)
        args = parser.parse_args()
        render = args.render
        test_model = args.test_model

        return render, test_model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LunarLanderDQNAgent()
```

**SUMMARY**

I have the above code running smoothly for a couple of seconds then the rendering acts like a slideshow and I dont currently have the knowledge regarding the tools I used to identify the cause. I'd like to know if anyone can clearly see parts of code that are redundant and causing the execution to slow down or if some parts are just greedy and should be left out to increase performance and execution speed.

I am running 16Gb of RAM, an i7-9700K and and RTX 2070 Super for this if this is of any use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The batch size is whats causing your execution to slow down. If you increase it, your render will go faster. However, if you do so, you will end up doing less steps by episode.